# MapReduce in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, aggregation-framework

My Mongo collection : `Impressions` has docs in the following format:-

```
   {
        _uid: 10,
        "impressions": [
            {
                "pos": 6,
                "id": 123,
                "service": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "pos": 0,
                "id": 128,
                "service": "electronics"
            },
            {
                "pos": 2,
                "id": 127,
                "service": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "pos": 2,
                "id": 125,
                "service": "electronics"
            },
            {
                "pos": 10,
                "id": 124,
                "service": "electronics"
            }
        ]
      },
     {
        _uid: 11,
        "impressions": [
            {
                "pos": 1,
                "id": 124,
                "service": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "pos": 10,
                "id": 124,
                "service": "electronics"
            },
            {
                "pos": 1,
                "id": 123,
                "service": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "pos": 21,
                "id": 122,
                "service": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "pos": 3,
                "id": 125,
                "service": "electronics"
            },
            {
                "pos": 10,
                "id": 121,
                "service": "electronics"
            }
            ]
         },
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

Each of the doc in the collection has `"impressions"` key which is an array of dictionaries. In each dictionary `"id"` is the id of the entity, `"service"` is the service type and `"pos"`is the position of the item in the search page results. My aim is to find out the count of number of impressions for every `"id"` in each category.
So for the above data for `"service"` == `"furniture"`, I want to have this as my aggregation results:-

```
[
{"id": 123,"impressions_count":2},
{"id": 127,"impressions_count":1},
{"id": 124,"impressions_count":1},
{"id": 122,"impressions_count":1}
]
```

I tried to aggregate on the "id" using MAPREDUCE via following function in a python script

```
def fetch_impressions():
    try:
        imp_collection = get_mongo_connection('Impressions')
        map = Code("""
                function(){
                    for( x in this.impressions){
                        var flat_id = x['id'];
                        var service_type = x['service']
                        emit(parseInt(flat_id),1);
                        }
                    };
                """)

                        """)
        reduce = Code("""
                        function(a,b){
                            return Array.sum(b);
                            };
                        """)

        results = imp_collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, 'aggregation_result')
        return results
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)
```

But I'm getting the results as None, probably because of the faulty map function.I'm new to Javascript and Mongo kindly help!

Comment: what are you trying to do? what is the expected result?

Comment: @user3100115
Updated the question, Sorry for the delay !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [aggregation framework](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework)

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = conn.test
col =  db.collection

for doc in col.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$impressions'}, 
    {'$match': {'impressions.service': 'furniture'}}, 
    {'$group': {'_id': '$impressions.id', 'impressions_count': {'$sum': 1}}}, 
    ]):
    print(doc)
```

Or more efficiently using the [`$map`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) and the [`$setDifference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators.

```
col.aggregate([
    { "$project": { "impressions": {"$setDifference": [{ "$map": { "input": "$impressions", "as": "imp", "in": { "$cond": { "if": { "$eq": [ "$$imp.service", "furniture" ] }, "then": "$$imp.id", "else": 0 }}}}, [0]]}}}, 
    { "$unwind": "$impressions" }, 
    { "$group": { "_id": "$impressions", "impressions_count": { "$sum": 1 }}}
])
```

Which yields:

```
{'_id': 122.0, 'impressions_count': 1}
{'_id': 124.0, 'impressions_count': 1}
{'_id': 127.0, 'impressions_count': 1}
{'_id': 123.0, 'impressions_count': 2}
```

Comment: This still does not answer the question of how would we approach this using `map_reduce()` API

Comment: Why would you want to use `map_reduce` when there is a better way to do this? @AyushKSingh

Comment: completely agree on that, but we should also answer the question using map-reduce before offering a better solution so that the user who asks question leaves the site learning not only a new and better way but also realizes the problem in their solution and it's corresponding fix.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tool that lets you run MongoDB Map/Reduce in Python

https://mreduce.com

```
import random
import threading

import bson
import pymongo

import mreduce


mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://your_mongodb_server")

def map_func(document):
    for impression in document["impressions"]:
        yield document["id"], 1

def reduce_func(id, prices):
    return sum(prices)

worker_functions = {
    "exampleMap": map_func,
    "exampleReduce": reduce_func
}

api = mreduce.API(
    api_key = "...",
    mongo_client = mongo_client
)

project_id = "..."

thread = threading.Thread(
    target=api.run,
    args=[project_id, worker_functions]
)
thread.start()

job = api.submit_job(
    projectId=project["_id"],
    mapFunctionName="exampleMap",
    reduceFunctionName="exampleReduce",
    inputDatabase="db",
    inputCollection="impressions",
    outputDatabase="db",
    outputCollection="impressions_results"
)
result = job.wait_for_result()
for key, value in result:
    print("Key: " + key, ", Value: " + str(value))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: I did explain why it solves the problem, it allows you to run map/reduce in Python like OP is asking.  Also I did say that I wrote the tool

Comment: @Dharman ErlVolton is my other account I was accidentally signed into.  Also I updated the code so it solves the specific problem OP had, totalling impressions per ID