# Conditions in Find, Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection with doc as follows:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a9378ee2874f0ed7b7cb7e"),
    "_uid" : 10,
    "impressions" : [
            {
                    "pos" : 6,
                    "id" : 123,
                    "service" : "furniture"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 0,
                    "id" : 128,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 2,
                    "id" : 127,
                    "service" : "furniture"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 2,
                    "id" : 125,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 10,
                    "id" : 124,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a9378ee2874f0ed7b7cb7f"),
    "_uid" : 11,
    "impressions" : [
            {
                    "pos" : 1,
                    "id" : 124,
                    "service" : "furniture"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 10,
                    "id" : 124,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 1,
                    "id" : 123,
                    "service" : "furniture"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 21,
                    "id" : 122,
                    "service" : "furniture"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 3,
                    "id" : 125,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            },
            {
                    "pos" : 10,
                    "id" : 121,
                    "service" : "electronics"
            }
    ]
}
```

My aim is to find all the `"id"` in a particular `"service"` say `"furniture"` i.e to get results like this:

```
[122,123,124,127]
```

But i'm not able to figure out how to frame the condition in

```
db.collection_name.find()
```

because of the difficulty of having condition for the 'n' th element in an array, `"impressions[n]":"value"`.

One option is to use the `"id"`s obtained perform aggregate operation to find impressions for each `"id"` for a service as suggested by the answer to this question I asked earlier:-
[MapReduce in PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456788/mapreduce-in-pymongo).

But I only want the list of distinct `'id'` in a service not the impressions. 
Kindly help!

Comment: Can you please double-check your document above? The doc above has 2 _uid fields and 2 "impresssions" fields, should they be 2 seperate docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [aggregration framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for meaningful results. So much like this:

```python
result = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "impressions.service": "furniture"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$impressions" },
    { "$match": {
        "impressions.service": "furniture"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$impressions.id"
    }}
])
```

Or better yet with MongoDB 2.6 or greater, which can remove the array items unmatched "prior" to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) with [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```python
result = db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "impressions.service": "furniture"
    }},
    { "$redact": {
       "$cond": {
           "if": { 
               "$eq": [
                   { "$ifNull": [ "$service", "furniture" ] },
                   "furniture"
               ]
           },
           "then": "$$DESCEND",
           "else": "$$PRUNE"
       }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$impressions" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$impressions.id"
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```python
{ "_id" : 122 }
{ "_id" : 124 }
{ "_id" : 127 }
{ "_id" : 123 }
```

Not a plain "list", but just transform it, therefore :

```python
def mapper (x):
    return x["_id"]

map(mapper,result)
```

Or:

```python
map(lambda x: x["_id"], result)
```

To give you:

```python
[122, 124, 127, 123]
```

If you want it "sorted" then either add a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage at the end of the aggregation pipeline or sort the resulting list in code.